# Comparing fields

Tags: asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-3, linq

Hi I am trying to create a registration page.I am using linq to sql for creating the data models.And have created an aditional class for accesing the data I do not know if this is the corect way to do it but this is how managed to make it work.

Here is my code:

```
    [Required]
    [DataType(DataType.Password)]
    [Display(Name="Password")]
    public string password
    {
        get { return member.Password; }
        set { member.Password = value; }
    }

    [Required]
    [DataType(DataType.Password)]
    [Display(Name = "Confirm Password")]
    [Compare("Password" , ErrorMessage = "The password and confirm pasword do not match")]
    public string confirmPassword { get;set; }
```

My database does not have a field for confirm password.I am using the database generated for the Membership API.

When I try to submit the data I get this error:

```
Could not find a property named Password.
```

How can I corect this?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The error is absolutely correct.

`public string password` is lowercase, and .Net is (mostly) case-sensitive.

Answer (score 1):

Change your property name to

```
public string Password
```

The ***Compare attributes*** check the properties name and it is case sensitive, so if the names are not identical be experiencing that exception you were getting.